# JavaScript new Date Ordinal (st, nd, rd, th)

Tags: javascript, date, ordinal-indicator

If at all possible, without JavaScript libraries or lots of clunky code I am looking for the simplest way to format a date two weeks from now in the following format:

`13th March 2013`

The code I am using is:

```
var newdate = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
document.body.innerHTML = newdate;
```

which returns the date and time two weeks from now, but like this:
Wed Mar 27 2013 21:50:29 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Here is the code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CT7Fm/40/).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: apart from a missing "of" I have no problem with that date

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript

Comment: I was wondering how to do exactly the opposite ? I don't want to bring up new thread so if someone has the link I'd appreciate it

Comment: This is outside of the scope of the original question, but I don't suppose anyone has tackled ordinals in other languages? I know French does theirs a bit different, for example.

Answer (score 155):

Note this works for day numbers from 1 to 31.

```js
const nth = (d) => {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th';
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
  }
};

// test code

const fortnightAway = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
const date = fortnightAway.getDate();
const month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"][fortnightAway.getMonth()];

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = `In two weeks it will be the ${date}<sup>${nth(date)}</sup> of ${month} ${fortnightAway.getFullYear()}`;

// test
const dates = [...Array(32).keys()].slice(1).map(i => `${i}${nth(i)}`)
console.log(dates.join(", "))
```

```css
sup {
  font-size: x-small
}
```

```html
<span id="date"></span>
```

Here is a version for any number

```js
const nth = (d) => {
  const dString = String(d);
  const last = +dString.slice(-2);
  if (last > 3 && last < 21) return 'th';
  switch (last % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
  }
};

// test
const numbers = [...Array(1225).keys()].map(i => `${i}${nth(i)}`)
console.log(numbers.join(", "))
```

Oneliner suggested in comments

```js
const nth = n => n>3&&n<21?"th":n%10==1?"st":n%10==2?"nd":n%10==3?"rd":"th";

// to call: nth(i)

// test
document.getElementById("nums").innerHTML =  [...Array(1225).keys()].map(i => `<pre>${String(i).padStart(3," ")}<sup>${nth(i)}</sup></pre>`).join(" ");
```

```css
pre { display:inline-block; margin:2px; }
```

```html
<div id="nums"></div>
```

If you do not like switch, this will work equally well

```js
const nth = (d) => {
  const last = +String(d).slice(-2);
  if (last > 3 && last < 21) return 'th';
  const remainder = last % 10;
  if (remainder === 1) return "st";
  if (remainder === 2) return "nd";
  if (remainder === 3) return "rd";
  return "th";
};

// test
const numbers = [...Array(1225).keys()].map(i => `${i}${nth(i)}`)
console.log(numbers.join(", "))
```

Comment: Works perfect... +1 for `d>3 && d<21`

Comment: For clarity, I'd probably code the exceptions as either:  if (n == 11 || n == 12 || n == 13) return "th";    or:    if (n >= 11 && n <= 13) return "th";

Comment: That is missing 21,22,23

Comment: **Ordinal function (compressed):** `function nth(n){return n>3&&n<21?"th":n%10==2?"nd":n%10==2?"nd":n%10==3?"rd":"th"}`

Comment: Minor typo in the above function, this should work: `function nth(n){return n>3&&n<21?"th":n%10==1?"st":n%10==2?"nd":n%10==3?"rd":"th"}`

Answer (score 37):

Here is a one liner inspired by the other answers. It is tested and will take 0 and negative numbers.

```
function getOrdinalNum(n) {
  return n + (n > 0 ? ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(n > 3 && n < 21) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10] : '');
}
```

Update 2020-06-23. The following is a better readable answer of the function above:

```
const getOrdinalNum = (number) => {
  let selector;

  if (number <= 0) {
    selector = 4;
  } else if ((number > 3 && number < 21) || number % 10 > 3) {
    selector = 0;
  } else {
    selector = number % 10;
  }

  return number + ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', ''][selector];
};
```

Comment: This won't work for 111, 112, 113, 211, etc. This might work for all.


`["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][n % 100 > 10 && n % 100 < 14) || n % 10 > 3 ? 0 : n % 10]`

but there's no such case for dates. In case someone needs to use it for any positive integer

Answer (score 11):

If you are a fan of moment.js, then you can make it with format("Do")

Examples

```
var newdate = new Date();
moment(newdate).format("Do MMMM YYYY")
//Returns 1st January 2020

moment("01/01/2020", "MM/DD/YYYY").format("Do")
//Returns 1st

moment("01/01/2020", "MM/DD/YYYY").format("Do MMM YYYY")
//Returns 1st Jan 2020
```

Answer (score 10):

I was doing this for dates as well, but because the day of month can only be between 1 and 31, I ended up with a simplified solution.

```
function dateOrdinal(dom) {
    if (dom == 31 || dom == 21 || dom == 1) return dom + "st";
    else if (dom == 22 || dom == 2) return dom + "nd";
    else if (dom == 23 || dom == 3) return dom + "rd";
    else return dom + "th";
};
```

or compact version using conditional operators

```
function dateOrdinal(d) {
    return d+(31==d||21==d||1==d?"st":22==d||2==d?"nd":23==d||3==d?"rd":"th")
};
```

http://jsben.ch/#/DrBpl

Answer (score 7):

There are a lot of good answers here already, although one that makes use of [Intl.PluralRules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/PluralRules/PluralRules), which standardises the classification of ordinals across locales, may still be useful.

Below are some implementations for `en-GB`.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4bv8kz31/)

- a one liner:

  ```js
  console.log({one:'st',two:'nd',few:'rd',other:'th'}[new Intl.PluralRules('en-GB', { type: 'ordinal' }).select(new Date().getDate())])
  ```
- a verbose example:

  ```js
  const suffixMap = {
    one: 'st',
    two: 'nd',
    few: 'rd',
    other: 'th',
  };
  const locale = 'en-GB';
  const moment = new Date();
  const dayOfMonth = moment.getDate();
  const pluralRuleOptions = {
    type: 'ordinal',
  };
  const pluralRule = new Intl.PluralRules(locale, pluralRuleOptions);
  const ordinal = pluralRule.select(dayOfMonth);
  console.log(suffixMap[ordinal])
  ```

```js
const suffix = {
  one: 'st',
  two: 'nd',
  few: 'rd',
  other: 'th',
};

document.getElementById("tomorrow-month").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { month: 'long' }).format(new Date(Date.now() + 86400000));
document.getElementById("tomorrow-day").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { day: 'numeric' }).format(new Date(Date.now() + 86400000));
document.getElementById("tomorrow-ordinal").innerHTML = suffix[new Intl.PluralRules('en-GB', { type: 'ordinal' }).select(new Date(Date.now() + 86400000).getDate())];

document.getElementById("yesterday-month").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { month: 'long' }).format(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000));
document.getElementById("yesterday-day").innerHTML = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { day: 'numeric' }).format(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000));
document.getElementById("yesterday-ordinal").innerHTML = suffix[new Intl.PluralRules('en-GB', { type: 'ordinal' }).select(new Date(Date.now() - 86400000).getDate())];
```

```html
Tomorrow, on <span id="tomorrow-month"></span> <span id="tomorrow-day"></span><sup id="tomorrow-ordinal"></sup>, I ordered a time machine.
It arrived yesterday on <span id="yesterday-month"></span> <span id="yesterday-day"></span><sup id="yesterday-ordinal"></sup>.
```

Comment: Is there any best practice for a suffix map that would support multiple languages?

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/q/48301860/329062 which suggests building a table for all dates instead of trying to calculate the ordinal.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a simple function that works with any number:

```
function getOrdinal(n) {
    let ord = ["st", "nd", "rd"]
    let exceptions = [11, 12, 13]
    let nth = 
    ord[(n % 10) - 1] == undefined || exceptions.includes(n % 100) ? "th" : ord[(n % 10) - 1]
    return n + nth
}
```

It can accept a number or number as a string. For example:

```
getOrdinal(28)        //Outputs: 28th
getOrdinal('108')     //Outputs: 108th
```

Answer (score 5):

One more solution in the sea of solutions.

```
let suffix = (day >= 4 &&  day <= 20) || (day >= 24 && day <= 30)
    ? "th"
    : ["st", "nd", "rd"][day % 10 - 1];
```

Comment: +1 for brevity *and* clarity, thank you! I read all the reasonably short ones and this one resonated on both counts.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of formatting answers, so I'll just work on the nth of any integer-

```
Number.prototype.nth= function(){
    if(this%1) return this;
    var s= this%100;
    if(s>3 && s<21) return this+'th';
    switch(s%10){
        case 1: return this+'st';
        case 2: return this+'nd';
        case 3: return this+'rd';
        default: return this+'th';
    }
}
```

Comment: The if is for teens, so 13 is 13th and not 13rd.

Comment: Why the `this%1`? Mod 1 is always 0 so the statement will always fail, no?

Answer (score 4):

If you are a fan of dayjs, which is now preferred over moment, here is an example:

you can just do `dayjs(date).format('Do')` but I've included an example to show how you can use it with any format you want.

Note that date ordinality is available with Dayjs advanced formats.

```
var advancedFormat = require('dayjs/plugin/advancedFormat')
dayjs.extend(advancedFormat)

// date variable - your date to format eg:- 2022-04-01T21:27:00
dayjs(date).format('dddd, MMMM Do [at] h:mma')
```

Output for above example (2022-04-01T21:27:00):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Lots of answers, here's another:

```js
function addOrd(n) {
  var ords = [, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'];
  var ord, m = n % 100;
  return n + ((m > 10 && m < 14) ? 'th' : ords[m % 10] || 'th');
}

// Return date string two weeks from now (14 days) in 
// format 13th March 2013
function formatDatePlusTwoWeeks(d) {
  var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
    'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
  ];

  // Copy date object so don't modify original
  var e = new Date(d);

  // Add two weeks (14 days)
  e.setDate(e.getDate() + 14);
  return addOrd(e.getDate()) + ' ' + months[e.getMonth()] + ' ' + e.getFullYear();
}

console.log(formatDatePlusTwoWeeks(new Date()));

// Alternative using Intl.DateTimeFormat
function datePlusTwoWeeks(date = new Date()) {
  let d = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() + 14);
  let parts = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en',{
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  }).formatToParts(d).reduce((acc, part) => {
    acc[part.type] = part.value;
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));
  return `${addOrd(parts.day)} ${parts.month} ${parts.year}`;
}

console.log(datePlusTwoWeeks())
```

Answer (score 2):

This works great for me

```
ordinal(n) {
    var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
    var v = n%100;
    return n + (s[(v-20)%10] || s[v] || s[0]);
}
```

usage:

```
console.log(ordinal(11))
OUTPUT: 11th
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modern approach using the [`Intl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) library:

```js
const locale = 'en-US',
      suffixMap = { one: 'st', two: 'nd', few: 'rd', other: 'th' },
      pluralRule = new Intl.PluralRules(locale, { type: 'ordinal', }),
      withOrdinal = (n) => `${n}${suffixMap[pluralRule.select(n)]}`,
      dateFmt = Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { month: 'long', year: 'numeric' }),
      formatDate = (date) => `${withOrdinal(date.getDate())} ${dateFmt.format(date)}`;

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Here is another approach.

```js
const locale = 'en-US',
      suffixMap = { one: 'st', two: 'nd', few: 'rd', other: 'th' },
      pluralRule = new Intl.PluralRules(locale, { type: 'ordinal', }),
      withOrdinal = (n) => `${n}${suffixMap[pluralRule.select(n)]}`,
      dayOfWeekFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { weekday: 'long' }),
      monthFormatter = Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, { month: 'long' });

const getDayInfo = () => {
  const now = new Date(),
        dayOfWeek = now.getDay(),
        currentMonth = now.getMonth(),
        currDate = new Date(now.getTime());
  let occurance = 1;
  
  while (currDate.getMonth() > currentMonth - 1) {
    currDate.setDate(currDate.getDate() - 1);
    if (currDate.getDay() === dayOfWeek) {
      occurance++;
    }
  }
    
  const ordinal = withOrdinal(occurance),
        weekday = dayOfWeekFormatter.format(now),
        month = monthFormatter.format(now);
  
  return `Today is the ${ordinal} ${weekday} of ${month}`;
};

const info = getDayInfo();

console.log(info);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but this should work:

```
function ordinal(number) {
  number = Number(number)
  if(!number || (Math.round(number) !== number)) {
    return number
  }
  var signal = (number < 20) ? number : Number(('' + number).slice(-1))
  switch(signal) {
    case 1:
      return number + 'st'
    case 2:
      return number + 'nd'
    case 3:
      return number + 'rd'
    default:
      return number + 'th'
  }
}

function specialFormat(date) {
  // add two weeks
  date = new Date(+date + 12096e5)
  var months = [
    'January'
    , 'February'
    , 'March'
    , 'April'
    , 'May'
    , 'June'
    , 'July'
    , 'August'
    , 'September'
    , 'October'
    , 'November'
    , 'December'
  ]
  var formatted = ordinal(date.getDate())
  formatted += ' ' + months[date.getMonth()]
  return formatted + ' ' + date.getFullYear()
}

document.body.innerHTML = specialFormat(new Date())
```

Answer (score 0):

As many has mentioned, here is another answer.

This is directly based on **@kennebec**'s answer, which I found the most simplest way to get this **date Ordinal** generated for given `JavaScript` date:

**I created two `prototype function` as follows:**

```
Date.prototype.getDateWithDateOrdinal = function() {
    var d = this.getDate();  // from here on I've used Kennebec's answer, but improved it.
    if(d>3 && d<21) return d+'th';
    switch (d % 10) {
        case 1:  return d+"st";
        case 2:  return d+"nd";
        case 3:  return d+"rd";
        default: return d+"th";
    }
};

Date.prototype.getMonthName = function(shorten) {
    var monthsNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    var monthIndex = this.getMonth();
    var tempIndex = -1;
    if (monthIndex == 0){ tempIndex = 0 };
    if (monthIndex == 1){ tempIndex = 1 };
    if (monthIndex == 2){ tempIndex = 2 };
    if (monthIndex == 3){ tempIndex = 3 };
    if (monthIndex == 4){ tempIndex = 4 };
    if (monthIndex == 5){ tempIndex = 5 };
    if (monthIndex == 6){ tempIndex = 6 };
    if (monthIndex == 7){ tempIndex = 7 };
    if (monthIndex == 8){ tempIndex = 8 };
    if (monthIndex == 9){ tempIndex = 9 };
    if (monthIndex == 10){ tempIndex = 10 };
    if (monthIndex == 11){ tempIndex = 11 };

    if (tempIndex > -1) {
        this.monthName = (shorten) ? monthsNames[tempIndex].substring(0, 3) : monthsNames[tempIndex];
    } else {
        this.monthName = "";
    }

    return this.monthName;
};
```

**Note:** just include the above `prototype` functions within your `JS Script` and use it as described bellow.

And whenever there is a `JS` **date** I need to generate the date with date ordinal I use that prototype method as follows on that `JS` **date:**

```
var myDate = new Date();
// You may have to check your JS Console in the web browser to see the following
console.log("date with date ordinal: "+myDate.getDateWithDateOrdinal()+" "+myDate.getMonthName()+" "+myDate.getFullYear());

// or I will update the Div. using jQuery
$('#date').html("date with date ordinal: "+myDate.getDateWithDateOrdinal()+" "+myDate.getMonthName()+" "+myDate.getFullYear());
```

And it will print out date with *date ordinal* as shown in the following **live demo**:

```js
 Date.prototype.getMonthName = function(shorten) {
  var monthsNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var monthIndex = this.getMonth();
  var tempIndex = -1;
     if (monthIndex == 0){ tempIndex = 0 };
     if (monthIndex == 1){ tempIndex = 1 };
     if (monthIndex == 2){ tempIndex = 2 };
     if (monthIndex == 3){ tempIndex = 3 };
     if (monthIndex == 4){ tempIndex = 4 };
     if (monthIndex == 5){ tempIndex = 5 };
     if (monthIndex == 6){ tempIndex = 6 };
     if (monthIndex == 7){ tempIndex = 7 };
     if (monthIndex == 8){ tempIndex = 8 };
     if (monthIndex == 9){ tempIndex = 9 };
     if (monthIndex == 10){ tempIndex = 10 };
     if (monthIndex == 11){ tempIndex = 11 };

     if (tempIndex > -1) {
   this.monthName = (shorten) ? monthsNames[tempIndex].substring(0, 3) : monthsNames[tempIndex];
     } else {
      this.monthName = "";
     }

     return this.monthName;
 };

    Date.prototype.getDateWithDateOrdinal = function() {
  var d = this.getDate();  // from here on I've used Kennebec's answer, but improved it.
     if(d>3 && d<21) return d+'th';
     switch (d % 10) {
            case 1:  return d+"st";
            case 2:  return d+"nd";
            case 3:  return d+"rd";
            default: return d+"th";
        }
 };

 var myDate = new Date();
    // You may have to check your JS Console in the web browser to see the following
 console.log("date with date ordinal: "+myDate.getDateWithDateOrdinal()+" "+myDate.getMonthName()+" "+myDate.getFullYear());
    
    // or I will update the Div. using jQuery
    $('#date').html("date with date ordinal: "+myDate.getDateWithDateOrdinal()+" "+myDate.getMonthName()+" "+myDate.getFullYear());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="date"></p>
```

.

Answer (score 0):

A short and compact solution:

```js
function format(date, tmp){
  return [
    (tmp = date.getDate()) + 
      ([, 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][/1?.$/.exec(tmp)] || 'th'),
    [ 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
      'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
      'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'
    ][date.getMonth()],
    date.getFullYear()
  ].join(' ')
}


// 14 days from today

console.log('14 days from today: ' + 
  format(new Date(+new Date + 14 * 864e5)));

// test formatting for all dates within a month from today

var day = 864e5, today = +new Date;
for(var i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
  console.log('Today + ' + i + ': ' + format(new Date(today + i * day)))
}
```

(The compact regex-based approach for getting the ordinal suffix [appears](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/outputting-ordinal-numbers-1st-2nd-3rd) [several](https://gist.github.com/furf/986113/c9772d6001db2120a1307634906419ee1f179f69) [places](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=503217) around the web, original source unknown)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 Date.prototype.getMonthName = function(shorten) {
  var monthsNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var monthIndex = this.getMonth();
  var tempIndex = -1;
     if (monthIndex == 0){ tempIndex = 0 };
     if (monthIndex == 1){ tempIndex = 1 };
     if (monthIndex == 2){ tempIndex = 2 };
     if (monthIndex == 3){ tempIndex = 3 };
     if (monthIndex == 4){ tempIndex = 4 };
     if (monthIndex == 5){ tempIndex = 5 };
     if (monthIndex == 6){ tempIndex = 6 };
     if (monthIndex == 7){ tempIndex = 7 };
     if (monthIndex == 8){ tempIndex = 8 };
     if (monthIndex == 9){ tempIndex = 9 };
     if (monthIndex == 10){ tempIndex = 10 };
     if (monthIndex == 11){ tempIndex = 11 };

     if (tempIndex > -1) {
   this.monthName = (shorten) ? monthsNames[tempIndex].substring(0, 3) : monthsNames[tempIndex];
     } else {
      this.monthName = "";
     }

     return this.monthName;
 };

    Date.prototype.getDateWithDateOrdinal = function() {
  var d = this.getDate();  // from here on I've used Kennebec's answer, but improved it.
     if(d>3 && d<21) return d+'th';
     switch (d % 10) {
            case 1:  return d+"st";
            case 2:  return d+"nd";
            case 3:  return d+"rd";
            default: return d+"th";
        }
 };

 var myDate = new Date();
    // You may have to check your JS Console in the web browser to see the following
 console.log("date with date ordinal: "+myDate.getDateWithDateOrdinal()+" "+myDate.getMonthName()+" "+myDate.getFullYear());
    
    // or I will update the Div. using jQuery
    $('#date').html("date with date ordinal: "+myDate.getDateWithDateOrdinal()+" "+myDate.getMonthName()+" "+myDate.getFullYear());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="date"></p>
```

Comment: 1. Why no comments. 2. Why hide the code? 3. You can remove the tempindex and just have `var monthIndex = this.getMonth(); return (shorten) ? monthsNames[monthIndex].substring(0, 3) : monthsNames[monthIndex];`

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSuffixForDate(day) {
  const lastNumberOfTheDay = day[day.length];

  const suffixes = {
    1: () => 'st',
    21: () => 'st',
    31: () => 'st',
    2: () => 'nd',
    22: () => 'nd',
    3: () => 'rd',
    23: () => 'rd',
  };

  return suffixes[lastNumberOfTheDay] !== undefined ? `${day}${suffixes[lastNumberOfTheDay]()}` : `${day}th`;
}

const date = new Date();
const formattedDate = `${getSuffixForDate(date.getDate())} ${monthNames[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`;
```

A human readable version...

Comment: It's just a lot simpler solution. It will check the last number in day and then check if it exists in the object. If it does then return the correct suffix and then if not return `th`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a readable, ES+ kinda version.

```js
const getDateSuffix = (date) => {
  const thExpections = date => [11, 12, 13].some(exception => exception === date);
  const lastDigit = date % 10;

  if (thExpections(date) || lastDigit === 0 || lastDigit > 3) return `${date}th`;
  if (lastDigit === 1) return `${date}st`;
  if (lastDigit === 2) return `${date}nd`;
  return `${date}rd`;
};

const monthNames = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "July",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];

const twoWeeksFromNow = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
console.log(`Two weeks from now: ${getDateSuffix(twoWeeksFromNow.getDate())} ${monthNames[twoWeeksFromNow.getMonth()]} ${twoWeeksFromNow.getFullYear()}`)

console.log(`
=================
Test date suffixes:`);
const logOutDates = new Array(31).fill(0).forEach((_, index) => console.log(getDateSuffix(index + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

> without JavaScript libraries or lots of clunky code

One simple approach to achieve this is in vanilla javascript would be to use a series of *three ternary statements* to determine the ordinal, like this:

```
let dateOrdinal = 'th';

dateOrdinal = ([1, 21, 31].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) ? 'st' : dateOrdinal;
dateOrdinal = ([2, 22].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) ? 'nd' : dateOrdinal;
dateOrdinal = ([3, 23].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) ? 'rd' : dateOrdinal;
```

It's not quite as human-readable, but you *could* also use a `switch/case` statement to make the same determination:

```
switch (true) {
  
  case ([1, 21, 31].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) : let dateOrdinal = 'st'; break;
  case ([2, 22].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) : let dateOrdinal = 'nd'; break;
  case ([3, 23].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) : let dateOrdinal = 'rd'; break;
  default : let dateOrdinal = 'th';
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
// GET DATE PARTS
const dateInTwoWeeks = new Date(+new Date + 12096e5);
const dateNumber = dateInTwoWeeks.getDate();
const dateMonth = dateInTwoWeeks.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'});
const dateYear = dateInTwoWeeks.getFullYear();

// DETERMINE DATE ORDINAL
let dateOrdinal = 'th';

dateOrdinal = ([1, 21, 31].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) ? 'st' : dateOrdinal;
dateOrdinal = ([2, 22].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) ? 'nd' : dateOrdinal;
dateOrdinal = ([3, 23].indexOf(dateNumber) > -1) ? 'rd' : dateOrdinal;

// FORMAT DATE AS STRING
const dateInTwoWeeksString = `${dateNumber}${dateOrdinal} ${dateMonth} ${dateYear}`; 

document.body.textContent = dateInTwoWeeksString;
```

Comment: I really, really dislike switch(true)

Comment: Go on then, @mplungjan. I'd be intrigued to hear why. I tend to prefer `switch / case` rather than endless `else if () {} else if () {} else if () {}` and I am _so_ pleased when I can actually deploy `switch / case` _without_ using `switch(true)`. All too often, I find that `switch(true)` is unavoidable in order to deploy `switch / case` in the first place.

Comment: I find it an abuse of a side effect. Please scroll up to my accepted answer for a much more readable version which is using switch as it is supposed to be used

Answer (score 0):

I think this is pretty cool way to get the date suffix

```
      getDateSuffix(datePart: number): string {
        const stAr = [1, 21, 31];
        const ndAr = [2, 22];
        const rdAr = [3, 23];
    
        const suffixesRaw = [
          { suffix: 'st', numbers: stAr },
          { suffix: 'nd', numbers: ndAr },
          { suffix: 'rd', numbers: rdAr },
        ];
    
        const suffixes = suffixesRaw
          .filter(x => x.numbers.filter(y => y == datePart).length > 0)
          .map(z => z.suffix);
    
        return suffixes.length > 0 ? suffixes[0] : 'th';
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Super simple functional implementation:

```
const ordinal = (d) => {
  const nth = { '1': 'st', '2': 'nd', '3': 'rd' }
  return `${d}${nth[d] || 'th'}`
}

const monthNames = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December']

const dateString = (date) => `${ordinal(date.getDate())} ${monthNames[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`

// Use like this: 
dateString(new Date()) // 18th July 2016
```

Comment: Unfortunately this method is too simple and doesn't work for days like the 21st.

Answer (score -1):

Strongly inspired by **@user2309185**'s.

```
const ordinal = (d) => {
  return d + (['st', 'nd', 'rd'][d % 10 - 1] || 'th')
}
```

Comment: I found an issue with this, `13` = `13rd`

Answer (score -1):

Here is an easy solution:

```
var date = today.getDate() + (today.getDate() % 10 == 1 && today.getDate() != 11 ? + 'st': (today.getDate() % 10 == 2 && today.getDate() != 12 ? + 'nd': 

(today.getDate() % 10 == 3 && today.getDate() != 13 ? + 'rd':'th')));
```