# Datetime formatting / customization in ejs

Tags: ejs

I show date by this in ejs

```
<%= new Date();%>
```

it give me result

> Tue Feb 02 2016 16:02:24 GMT+0530 (IST)

But I need to show as

> 19th January, 2016

How can I do this in ejs?

Comment: Note: The way you display a date differs from user  to user and country to country. See my answer below for more information.

Answer (score 38):

You can use [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

In your controller,

```
var moment = require('moment');
exports.index = function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', { moment: moment });
}
```

In your html,

```
<html>
    <h1><%= moment().format('Do MMMM, YYYY'); %></h1>
</html>
```

#### EDIT :

Using basic JS

```
const suffixMap = {
  one: 'st',
  two: 'nd',
  few: 'rd',
  other: 'th',
};

const date = new Date();
const dateDay = date.getDate();
const dateMonth = date.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'});
const dateYear = date.getFullYear();
const pluralRule = new Intl.PluralRules('en-GB', {type: 'ordinal'});
const dateOrdinal = suffixMap[pluralRule.select(dateDay)]

const ordinalDateString = `${dateDay}${dateOrdinal} ${dateMonth}, ${dateYear}`; 
// Expected output: 25th August, 2020
```

(Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342457/3804420))

```
const date = new Date();
const dateDay = date.getDate();
const dateMonth = date.toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'});
const dateYear = date.getFullYear();

// DETERMINE DATE ORDINAL
let dateOrdinal = 'th';

dateOrdinal = ([1, 21, 31].indexOf(dateDay) > -1) ? 'st' : dateOrdinal;
dateOrdinal = ([2, 22].indexOf(dateDay) > -1) ? 'nd' : dateOrdinal;
dateOrdinal = ([3, 23].indexOf(dateDay) > -1) ? 'rd' : dateOrdinal;

// FORMAT DATE AS STRING
const ordinalDateString = `${dateDay}${dateOrdinal} ${dateMonth}, ${dateYear}`; 
// Expected output: 25th August, 2020
```

Or, if you can live without ordinal day (th, nd, rd etc) you could use basic [JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat)

```
<%= new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: '2-digit'}).format(new Date()) %>
// Expected output: 25 August 2020
```

Answer (score 19):

You don't need moment js, you can simply use this

`<%= new Date().getFullYear();%>`

Answer (score 10):

Post is old but in case anyone runs into the issue.

You can eliminate installing moment and write one little line of code.
adding *.toDateString()* will provide you with the above format in ejs.

however, Moment is used for more detailed date, such as Day, or month or year etc...

Answer (score 4):

For a better code management, you can add the code(below) in app.js/server.js. This will save `moment` in the `res.locals.moment` at the time of starting the app. By doing this you can access the `moment` variable from any ejs page.
app.js/server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const moment = require("moment");

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
    res.locals.moment = moment;
    next();
  });
```

something.ejs

```
<p><%= moment(yourDateVariable).format('Do MMMM, YYYY')  %></p>
```

Here `Do` will result with `19th`.You can check it here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<%= moment(user.date).format( 'MMM-DD-YYYY') %>
```

Comment: If you add moment as a js script you can't because moment is not defined when the page is rendering. You have to pass moment to the .ejs file like the most upvoted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with most of the answers on this page is that they will format the date using the *server's* locale, but you probably want them rendered in the *user's* locale.  For example, if your server is in Virginia, your dates will be displayed in English in Eastern Time, but a user in another country will probably want them displayed differently.

The following code snippet will render `date` using the user's locale.  There's room for improvement, but it's a starting point:

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(
  new Date("<%= date.toISOString() %>").toLocaleDateString()
);
</script>
</p>
```

This takes the date on the server, converts it to an ISO-8601 string, and interpolates it into a little JavaScript snippet that runs client-side to produce the correct localized output.

For more information on toLocaleString, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Comment: If you're going to do this, you should probably avoid `document.write` and [use `.innerText` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73511088/2065702)

Answer (score 1):

```
// I have tested this in a for loop, it seems to be ok.

<% let d = new Date(); %>
<% let day = d.getDate(); %>
<% let m = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
"August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]; %>
<% let month = m[d.getMonth()]; %>
<% let year = d.getFullYear(); %>
<% let newdate = day + "th " + month + ", " + year; %>
<%= newdate %> // 22th July, 2022

// You can use the if...else statement for the ordinal number
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <h1>
  <%= new Date().getDate() %> <%= new Date().toLocaleString('default', {month: 'long'});  %>,<%= new Date().getFullYear();  %>
</h1>
```

Comment: This gives the output like "13 August,2023".Nothing new just after refering all the above answers this is the simplified answer