# How to format datetime in EJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSjOt.png)

I am trying to achieve the datetime format like this `1:00 am May 11 2020?`
I am using mongoDB and EJS

How can I do it in my code?

Here is my server.js code:

```
// Import
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/name_of_your_DB', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    quote: {
        type: String
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})
// Create an object that contains methods for mongoose to interface with MongoDB
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

// Setting
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

// Routes
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index')
});



app.post('/process', (req, res) => {
    const user = new User();
    user.name = req.body.name
    user.quote = req.body.quote
    user.save()
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error saving user:', err)
        })
    res.redirect('/quotes')
})


app.get('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, (err, quotes) => {
        var context = {
            quotes: quotes
        };

        if (err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong')
        }

        res.render("quotes", context);
    });
});

app.get('/delete', (req, res) => {
    User.remove({})
        .then(data => {
            res.json(data)
        })
    res.redirect('/quotes');
})

app.listen(8000)
```

And here's my EJS template:

```
    <div class="container bg-light" id="quote">
        <h2>Here are the awesome quotes!</h2>
        <div class="quote clearfix">
            <% for (var user in quotes) { %>
            <p class="quote"><b> "<%= quotes[user].quote %>"</b></p>
            <p class="date"> - "<%= quotes[user].name %>" at <%= quotes[user].created_at %></p>
            <hr>
            <% } %>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="/" class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Go back</button>
                </a>
                <a href="/delete" class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger float-right" id="delete">Delete</button>
                </a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can can I achieve that format in my code???????????
I appreciate all the answers thank you so much!
sdfdsfdsfdsf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)
To be able to use the `moment` npm module in ejs template, change the context variable:

```js
var context = {
   quotes: quotes,
   moment: moment
};
```

> Alternatively you can include Moment.js cdn script in the ejs template.

Then in your template, replace the corresponding ejs block with:
`<%= moment(quotes[user].created_at).format('hh:mm a MMM DD YYYY') %>`

Also check this out:
[How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/11389917)

Comment: To install moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151187/datetime-formatting-customization-in-ejs

Answer (score 0):

install `npm install moment --save` server side then

```
const moment = require('moment');
app.get('/quotes', (req, res) => {
    User.find({}, (err, quotes) => {
        var context = {
            quotes: quotes,
            moment
        };

        if (err) {
            console.log('Something went wrong')
        }

        res.render("quotes", context);
    });
});


<div class="container bg-light" id="quote">
        <h2>Here are the awesome quotes!</h2>
        <div class="quote clearfix">
            <% for (var user in quotes) { %>
            <p class="quote"><b> "<%= quotes[user].quote %>"</b></p>
            <p class="date"> - "<%= quotes[user].name %>" at <%= moment(quotes[user].created_at).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') %></p>
            <hr>
            <% } %>
            <div class="row">
                <a href="/" class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Go back</button>
                </a>
                <a href="/delete" class="col">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger float-right" id="delete">Delete</button>
                </a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[Others time and date format](https://momentjs.com/)