# Why does JavaScript add a timestamp to my Date when pulling from Postgres DB? Is there a way to get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, ejs

I have date in my Postgres DB with data type date ("2023-11-17) and in JS it shows up like this: 2023-11-16T23:00:00.000Z. Is there a way to get it in the same format like in Postgres - without time? I just want to show to user through ejs the date that they enter manually, like here: https://sive.rs/book - Date read.

I have looked through the whole internet and can not find some simple solution

Comment: There's only one kind of Date in JavaScript, and it represents a date and a time-of-day.  Your JavaScript Date instance does not actually look the way you say it looks; internally it's a single number. When you want to print a date or otherwise use a string representation, the [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) can be used to format your value in many different ways.

Comment: What do you use to query the database? The tool you've used has converted the date to JS Date ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date ) You need to format that date. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151187/datetime-formatting-customization-in-ejs where others wanted the same with ejs

Comment: When I need a date, I usually use my own implementation. I prefer the string `yyyy-mm-dd`. Most frameworks, e.g. Angular, support custom date, datetime and time implementations. I wouldn't use JavaScript's `Date` for dates (without time) or time (without date).

Comment: What database library are you using? If it's node-postgres, you can configure that to not parse `date` columns into JS `Date` objects, you would receive the raw string then.