# Convert YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to different format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I have a string in javascript as `2016-02-27 20:24:39` and I want to convert this as `27th Feb 08:24pm`.

What is the easiest way to do in Javascript?

Comment: @aldanux I can achieve by putting multiple conditions using `date.getHours(), date.getMinutes() etc...` My question is is there a Javascript function like php to easily convert the given date string to any format as we need.

Comment: Nothing built-in in JavaScript can do this. You need a third party library in order to achieve this.

Comment: Its an duplicate question, check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th)

Comment: @corgrath - You certainly don't "need" a third-party library: it's not that hard to write a function that does this. (Though I guess the question asks for the "easiest" way, which probably is with moment.js.)

Comment: @nnnnnn No one said its hard. I said it's not built-in into the language. Besides, I don't agree to reinventing wheels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a non-standard Date method [toLocaleFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)('%d-%b-%Y'). But appears to only work in Firefox for now.

Better use the [date.format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) library (only 125 lines)

```
var date = new Date('2016-02-27 20:24:39');
dateFormat(date, "dS mmm, h:MMTT");
```

Answer (score 5):

Checkout the JavaScript library called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

Since the default format for moment is ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), you don't need to tell moment how to parse the input String date (it defaults to ISO 8601), so you can simply write:

```
var now = "2016-02-27 20:24:39";
var formattedDate = moment(now).format("Do MMM HH:mma");
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/gekd97dy/

More information about displaying in different formats can be read here:

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: When I run the demo the console prints "1st Feb 20:02pm", yet the input value is "2016-02-27 20:24".

Comment: @corgrath `"Do MMM hh:mma"` is the correct format to get my desired output. https://jsfiddle.net/4nmqayyd/1/

Comment: @Malaiselvan didnt you say you wanted "27th"? That's "Qo".

Comment: @Malaiselvan sorry "Do"

Comment: @Roberto Thanks. Ive updated it to the correct format now.