# How to add ordinal suffixes to date script

Tags: php, ordinal

I have been trying to workout a script to add ordinal suffixes to my date script (seen below), but all attempts to write one or search on here for one has alas failed. Any insight to help fix the script would be greatly appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/wq5t4gh7/1/

```
var months = ["Month1", "Month2", "Month3", "Month4", "Month5", "Month5", "Month7", "Month8", "Month9", "Month10", "Month11", "Month12"];
var n = new Date();
var y = n.getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2);;
var m = n.getMonth();
var d = n.getDate();

document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = "The " + d + " of " + months[m] + ", 52" + y;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript new Date Ordinal (st, nd, rd, th)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might help

```
function nth(d) {
  if(d>3 && d<21) return 'th';
  switch (d % 10) {
        case 1:  return "st";
        case 2:  return "nd";
        case 3:  return "rd";
        default: return "th";
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add that into the script the date does not show up at all anymore. https://jsfiddle.net/wq5t4gh7/2/

Comment: You missed a closing `}` in your jsfiddle

Comment: And you have to actually call the function, not assume that it will run automagically