# How can I implement ordinal days to the AwesomeWM textclock widget?

Tags: linux, lua, calendar, window-managers, awesome-wm

I am using AwesomeWM v4.0-170-g6c24848-dirty, compiled against Lua 5.3.3; and I am starting to customise my widgets.

One of them is the clock, technically `wibox.widget.textclock()`. I have been able to alter the `format` in order to change the order, add custom messages like 'Today is Sunday, the 23 of July of 2017' but... no clue about the ordinals.

What I mean here is how to add that 'rd' to *23rd*, and make it change depending on the current date to, for example, *21**st***, *22**nd*** or *24**th***.

I have tried to add an `ordinal` variable before the format, followed to an if-else statement to determine its value depending on the day. This, however, does not work: I can't neither 'use' the date format outside the function, nor implement the variable inside `format`.

As far as I have read, variables in strings can be implemented like in the following example:

`print("Hello " .. name .. ", the value of key " .. k .. " is " .. v .. "!")`

However, this won't work here. I have run out of clues, can you shed me a light, please?

So far, I have coded a generic 'th' date format:

`mytextclock = wibox.widget.textclock(" %a %dth %B, %H:%M ", 60)`

...whose output would be: dayoftheweek dayth month, HH, MM.

Comment: For some JavaScript code, easily adaptable to Lua, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397495/107090.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background:**

At first I laid out the problem with two options in mind:

**1. Select the day from the whole output string**: After being processed by the program, use some kind of Bash `echo $2`(considering an output like `dayoftheweek day month hh:mm`) equivalence in Lua to...

**2. Treat the variable `day` individually from the start**: This would mean finding a way to get the variable without using the whole string, once we have it...

...process it later with an `if-else` structure which would alter the output depending on its value.

For speed reasons, I used the second way. I found easier and cleaner to get the variable from the start instead of dedicating some lines of code to the extraction from the output.

So I started using `%d` as my main variable to work, which is used in Lua to represent the day in a date. ([source](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html))

The main deal here was to convert the content of `%d` into a string:

```
day = "%d" -- This is supposed to be an integer now.
daynumber = tostring(day) -- Converts it to a string.
lastdigit = tostring(day, -1)
print(lastdigit) -- Output: d.
```

BOOM! Failure. This is not working, I hope somebody can say why in comments. The output if I print the latest char (-1) is always d, and if I try with -2 I will get the whole day value.

My main theory bases on the fact typing:

```
a = "%d"
print(a)
```

in the Lua interpreter (`$ lua` in your shell) just returns `%d`, no integers at all; but it's just a supposition. What's more, as far as I've read `%d` is used in a date context, not independently as the value of a variable.

**A possible solution:**

```
day = os.date("%d") -- First of all we grab the day from the system time.

-- As Lua displays the day with two digits, we are storing both of them in variables in order to process them separately later.
firstdigit = string.sub(day, 0, 1) 
lastdigit = string.sub(day, -1) 

-- We don't want Awesome to display '01st August' or '08th September'. We are going to suppress the '0'.
if firstdigit == "0" then
  day = lastdigit
end

-- Now we want to display the day with its respective ordinal: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th... we are going to process the last digit for this.
if lastdigit == "1" then
  ordinal = "st"
elseif lastdigit == "2" then
  ordinal = "nd"
elseif lastdigit == "3" then
  ordinal = "rd"
else
  ordinal = "th"
end

-- Finally, we display the final date.
mytextclock = wibox.widget.textclock(" %a " ..day..ordinal.. " %B %H:%M ", 60)
```

...so we get the following outputs:

[image: 1st]

[image: 2nd]

[image: 3rd]

[image: 5th]

Comment: I removed my answer. I got you wrong. you said that functions output was a text so I thought that its return value is a text, but I guess you meant that it displays something on a widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my conky file:

```
${exec /home/..../scripts/date-ordinal.sh}
```

`date-ordinal.sh` consists of:

```
#!/bin/bash

the_Day=$(date +'%d')

case $the_Day in
    1,21,31)
        echo "st"
        ;;
    2,22)
        echo "nd"
        ;;
    3,23)
        echo "rd"
        ;;
    *)
        echo "th"
        ;;
esac
```