# st, rd, th... date in ordinal form javascript

Tags: javascript, date, ordinal

I'm trying to get a program to display on this format: (example Tuesday, 19th of September 2017) but I'm getting hard time in putting the date in ordinal form like st,rd,th. Anyone can help me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th

Comment: @JoshLee I tried using the examples on that forum. I tried one example taken from that forum, unfortunately didn't work well. Because everytime I refresh instead of 20th, it  sometimes show 20th then 20rd then 20st... it doesnt stay on 20th...

Comment: This question is NOT  a duplicate of the linked question in the banner. This question is specifically about [tag:ordinal] `st` `nd` as in 1st or 2nd. As such, I'm nominating this question to be reopened.