# How to add SuperScript in date format in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add SuperScript in my date format .

Like am getting value from server "9/5/2019" and "9th May,2019 
I have to convert this into  "9th May,2019" , 
the th should be SuperScript.

for exp

const Newdate = "9-May-2019"

const NewDateDormat ="9th May,2019"

both date I have to display  both (Newdate and NewDateDormat) in 
"9th May,2019" this format .Here th should be "SuperScript".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th

Comment: Thanks but that are subscript , I have to display in superscript format

Answer (score 0):

When you insert it into DOM, you can just put the "th" between "sup" tags.

Comment: th am able to display the main problem  is th should be superscript ,