# Date Ordinal (st, nd, rd, th) in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

i need to get below date format.

```
30th July 2019
```

what i try,

```
<time-zone  time="{{ 2019-07-31 18:30:00 }}" format="DD MMM YYYY"></time-zone>
```

Result : 01 Aug 2019

Comment: no idea what that `time-zone` component is but angular has an inbuilt date pipe

Comment: Yes, i tried to get this format, 30th July 2019 but only problem i am having is to get 'th' or 'st' after date..

Comment: i am really looking for gets with suffix rd, th and st

Answer (score 11):

You can create a custom ordinal date pipe something like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ordinalDate'
})
export class OrdinalDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: Date): string {
    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }
   let months= ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July",
           "August","September","October","November","December"]
    return `${value.getDate()}${this.nth(value.getDate())} ${months[value.getMonth()]} ${value.getFullYear()}`;
  }

 nth(d) {
  if (d > 3 && d < 21) return 'th'; 
  switch (d % 10) {
    case 1:  return "st";
    case 2:  return "nd";
    case 3:  return "rd";
    default: return "th";
  }
}
}
```

Add pipe to module declarations and then use it on your date like

```
{{dateToFormat | ordinalDate}}
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipe-example-iw48nv)

[Logic inspired by this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397495/5621827)

Comment: There is a typo in your code. this.nth(value.getDate) should be this.nth(value.getDate())

Comment: It also doesn't work for months with 31 days. The if statement should read 
if ((d != 31) && (d >3 && d < 21)) return 'th'

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you already use the Moment.js library in your project, you can use its library method to convert to ordinal:

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/

```js
moment.localeData().ordinal(5); // 5th
```

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

```js
moment().format('Do MMMM YYYY'); // 5th September 2020
```

Comment: Really efficient to use if moment has been used in the project and you want ordinals without having to create a custom pipe or anything.

Answer (score 1):

you can build the custom date filter to add the suffix rd, th and st.

The custom filter is written in below snippet to get the date value **"dd"**
and based on date calculate the suffix

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.filter('dateSuffix', function ($filter) {
    var suffixes = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
    return function (input) {
        var dtfilter = $filter('date')(input, 'dd');
        var day = parseInt(dtfilter, 10);
        var relevantDigits = (day < 30) ? day % 20 : day % 30;
        var suffix = (relevantDigits <= 3) ? suffixes[relevantDigits] : suffixes[0];
        return $filter('date')(input, 'dd') + '' + suffix + ' ' + $filter('date')(input, 'MMM yyyy');
    };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.theDate = new Date();
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<span>{{ theDate | dateSuffix }}</span>    
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using date-fns:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import { format } from 'date-fns'

@Pipe({name: 'dateFnsFormat'})
export class DateFnsFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(date: Date, formatStr: string, options: any = {}): string {
    return format(date, formatStr, options)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<span>{{ selectedDate | dateFnsFormat: 'do MMMM, y' }}</span>
```

Result:

> 4th April, 2021

date-fns docs:

https://date-fns.org/v2.21.1/docs/format

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the headache. I wrote a simple function to handle this.

```
getDay()
{
    let dateNew = new Date(), day = dateNew.getDate(), ordinal = 'th';
    if (day == 2 || day == 22) ordinal = 'nd';
    if (day == 3 || day == 23) ordinal = 'rd';
    if (day == 21 || day == 1 || day == 31) ordinal = 'st';
    return day + '' + ordinal;
}
```

Usage

```
<p>{{ getDay() }}</p>
```

Output

> ```
> 12th
> ```