# Convert date as a string: "2021-08-12" to: "11th August, 2021"

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a date as a string like so: "2021-08-12". But, I want to display it nicely on the frontend like this : 11th August, 2021

Any recommendations on how to approach this?

Comment: convert it to Date object and from there create whatever format you want.

Comment: Did you mean `12th August, 2021`? or `2021-08-11`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript new Date Ordinal (st, nd, rd, th)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a library like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

```
moment().format("Do MMMM, YYYY");
```

- `Do` Day of Month 1st 2nd ... 30th 31st
- `MMMM` Month January February ... November December
- `YYYY` Year

See also [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

If 12th vs 11th was not a typo and you actually want to subtract a day from the date,
`moment().subtract(1, 'day')` before you display it as above.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. This worked nicely. Nice and clean. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

###### Note: don't use the following solution in production code. Use the "moment" library as @Codebling mentioned above.

You can do this with vanilla JavaScript as following. See the documentation for `Date.toLocaleString()`.

```js
const dateString = "2012-01-01";

function formatDate(dateString) {
  const suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd", "th"];
  const date = new Date(dateString + " 0:0:0");
  dateString = date.toLocaleString("en-US", {
    month: "long",
    year: "numeric",
  });

  const day = date.getDate();
  return `${day}${suffix[day < 4 ? day - 1 : 3]} ${dateString}`;
}

console.log(formatDate(dateString));
```

One little advice, build the habit of quickly looking up documentation instead of asking help on SO. I'm giving you this answer from the MDN docs. You can also try using `devdocs.io` with their offline web app to quickly lookup docs.

Comment: Yes I know that, just format as you like. I just gave a hint.

Comment: I'm not referring to the format, I'm referring to the incorrect date...it shows august 11 instead of august 12

Comment: yes, that is correct, this is because you are not supplying time when creating date object ;)

Comment: I don't think that part is relevant, it's the format they are after.

Comment: @vanowm, Dude you made me update that solution. Now it works

Comment: `getDay()` is a day of the week not day of the month ;)

Comment: Really? why is that? I quit :(

Comment: And still, for the reason I've mention before ****cough****time-not-supplied****cough**** I'm getting very weird result when changing date to `2012-01-01`: `32th December 2011`

Comment: Dang, now I get it! You could have just told me that! Thanks a lot :).

Comment: I've fixed the `2012-01-01`, but you should not pass `32th December 2011` as you clearly see I'm not doing any validation here!

Comment: Oh, never mind, that was my mistake. I replaced `getDay` with `getDate` in your original code, forgot about the `day+1`  later. Now your code works perfectly ;)

Comment: Recommend against vanilla Javascript for date manipulation. It will work correctly in 99% of cases and be horribly broken in the other 1%, not to mention being more code. When trying to do date math ad-hoc, one quickly runs into issues with leap years, leap seconds, not to mention the nightmare of time zones (things like daylight savings have historically been applied on different dates). In my experience I've found it worth it to invest in the library

Comment: Thanks for the information. At first I thought It would be easy to do. But after editing my code I also realized that it's a bad idea to mess with time and date manually :(

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to Date object and from there create whatever format you want:

```js
const myDate = "2021-08-21";

const date = new Date(myDate + " 0:0:0");

console.log(date.getDate() + "th " + date.toLocaleDateString("en-us", {month: "long"}) + ", " + date.getFullYear());
```