# adding a live date to a website using html and css?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make it so when someone goes on the site, it displays the current date for them in the format of this example: January 15th, 2022  .  I tried different scripts before but they all turn up in formats that I don't like.

Comment: There's a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th

Comment: You need JavaScript for that. As they fall into functionalities parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript new Date Ordinal (st, nd, rd, th)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is using **Javascript**. Javascript adds a new dimension to the websites.
So, you either use **vanilla Javascript** or use third-party libraries like Moment.js

In your case, I suggest using vanilla Javascript since you won't deal with dates too much.
Here is a code snippet that will help you out

```js
function getCurrentDate() {
    let date;
    let dateTime;
  
    date = new Date;
    dateTime = date.toISOString().split("T")[0];

    document.querySelector("#display-date").textContent =  dateTime;
}

getCurrentDate();
```

```html
<h1 id="display-date"></h1>
```

Also, remember to add a script tag at the end of the body tag to reference the Javascript code.

W3schools: [W3schools tutorial script tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)

Stackoverflow article: [Formatting dates in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397372/javascript-new-date-ordinal-st-nd-rd-th)

Comment: i tried to run this snippet and it returned the date in the format of yyyy/mm/dd, it works perfectly fine but i wanted to make it like: month day, year .. month being spelled out and day + year being digits, would that be possible?

Comment: Yes, that's possible, I've included a new link in my answer to another article in StackOverflow that teaches what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been mentioned how to integrate the date into the tag. But what has not been said yet is that you should consider the order. I would put the date injection after an onload. This way I would be on the safe side, that as soon as the DOM is loaded, my JS can also address the selector.

```js
window.onload = () => {    
  const el = document.getElementById('customDate');  
  el.innerHTML = (new Date).toISOString().split("T")[0];  
}
```

```html
<div id="customDate">waiting...</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with Java Script. Not without that.

```js
const d = new Date();
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = d;
```

```html
<h2>Date</h2>

<p id="date"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!-- Current Date -->
Current Date:
<input type="text" id="currentDate">
<br><br>
<script>
  var today = new Date();
  var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
  document.getElementById("currentDate").value = date;
</script>
<!-- Current Time -->
Current Time:
<input type="text" id="currentTime">
<br><br>
<script>
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  document.getElementById("currentTime").value = time;
</script>
<!-- Current Date and Time -->
Get Current Date and Time Both:
<input type="text" id="currentDateTime">
<br><br>
<script>
  var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
  document.getElementById("currentDateTime").value = dateTime;
</script>
```